# Writing java based JMS Client for WildFly10

Tags: client, jms, activemq-artemis, wildfly-10

I writing java based JMS Client for WildFly10 and I had problem

```
   Properties props = new Properties();
   props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,        "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
   props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, WILDFLY_REMOTING_URL);   // NOTICE: "http-     remoting" and port "8080"
   props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, JMS_USERNAME);
   props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, JMS_PASSWORD);
   //props.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
   context = new InitialContext(props);
```

i run your client code and i got this error:

```
Got initial Context: javax.naming.InitialContext@5442a311
Exception in thread “main” org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.NamingIOException: Failed to lookup [Root exception is java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory]
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ClientUtil.namingException(ClientUtil.java:49)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.execute(Protocol.java:104)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingStoreV1.lookup(RemoteNamingStoreV1.java:95)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore$1.operation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:276)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingOperation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:137)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.lookup(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:272)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:87)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:129)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
at com.almasprocess.model.bl.WildFlyJmsQueueSender.init(WildFlyJmsQueueSender.java:49)
at com.almasprocess.model.bl.WildFlyJmsQueueSender.main(WildFlyJmsQueueSender.java:43)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory
at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1$3.read(Protocol.java:159)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1$3.read(Protocol.java:149)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.BaseProtocolCommand.readResult(BaseProtocolCommand.java:59)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.handleClientMessage(Protocol.java:149)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingStoreV1$MessageReceiver$1.run(RemoteNamingStoreV1.java:232)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.loadClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:131)
at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.resolveClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:112)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadClassDescriptor(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1002)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1256)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1$3.read(Protocol.java:156)
… 7 more
Process finished with exit code 1
```

And I changed code like this and add  activemq lib in my project:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, WILDFLY_REMOTING_URL);   // NOTICE: "http-remoting" and port "8080"
props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, JMS_USERNAME);
props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, JMS_PASSWORD);
```

and i got this error :

```
 Got initial Context: javax.naming.InitialContext@6842775d
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
 at org.apache.activemq.jndi.ReadOnlyContext.lookup(ReadOnlyContext.java:225)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
 at com.almasprocess.model.bl.WildFlyJmsQueueSender.init(WildFlyJmsQueueSender.java:49)
 at com.almasprocess.model.bl.WildFlyJmsQueueSender.main(WildFlyJmsQueueSender.java:43)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

and standalone-full.xml config file like this :

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
            <server name="default">
                <security-setting name="#">
                    <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
                </security-setting>
                <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
                <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
                <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                </http-connector>
                <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
                <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                </http-acceptor>
                <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
                <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
                <jms-queue name="clickQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/clickQueue java:/jboss/exported/jms/queue/clickQueue"/>
                <jms-queue name="emailQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/EmailQueue java:/jboss/exported/jms/queue/EmailQueue"/>
                <jms-queue name="emailSendQueue" entries="java:/jboss/exported/jms/queue/EmailSendQueue"/>
                <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
                <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
            </server>
        </subsystem>
```

can you help me about error???
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Working example:

```
public class JMSClient {
   private static final String INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory";
   private static final String PROVIDER_URL = "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080";
   private static final String CONNECTION_FACTORY = "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";
   private static final String DESTINATION = "topic/irisWebBroadcaster";
   private static final String USERNAME = "jmsuser";
   private static final String PASSWORD = "qqq";

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Context namingContext = null;
      JMSContext context = null;

      try {
         final Properties env = new Properties();
         env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
         env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL);
         env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, USERNAME);
         env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, PASSWORD);

         namingContext = new InitialContext(env);

         ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) namingContext.lookup(CONNECTION_FACTORY);

         Destination destination = (Destination) namingContext.lookup(DESTINATION);

         context = connectionFactory.createContext(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

         JMSProducer producer = context.createProducer();
         producer.send(destination, "TEST");
      } catch (Exception e) {
          // print error messge
      } finally {
          if (namingContext != null) {
             try {
                namingContext.close();
             } catch (NamingException e) {
                // print error messge
             }
          }

          if (context != null) {
             context.close();
          }
      }
 }
```

}

Corresponding classpath (maybe excessive):

```
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/javax/annotation/api/main/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/javax/servlet/api/main/jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/javax/ejb/api/main/jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/javax/enterprise/api/main/cdi-api-1.2.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/log4j/logmanager/main/log4j-jboss-logmanager-1.1.2.Final.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/javax/inject/api/main/javax.inject-1.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/javax/ws/rs/api/main/jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/javax/jms/api/main/jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/main/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/main/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logging/main/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.0.3.Final.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/remote-naming/main/jboss-remote-naming-2.0.4.Final.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/xnio/main/xnio-api-3.3.4.Final.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/xnio/nio/main/xnio-nio-3.3.4.Final.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/remoting/main/jboss-remoting-4.0.18.Final.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/marshalling/main/jboss-marshalling-1.4.10.Final.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/marshalling/river/main/jboss-marshalling-river-1.4.10.Final.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/activemq/artemis/main/artemis-jms-client-1.1.0.wildfly-011.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/activemq/artemis/main/artemis-core-client-1.1.0.wildfly-011.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/activemq/artemis/main/artemis-commons-1.1.0.wildfly-011.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/activemq/artemis/main/artemis-selector-1.1.0.wildfly-011.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/commons/beanutils/main/commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/commons/collections/main/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/main/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jbossorg-1.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/org/slf4j/main/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jbossorg-1.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/org/slf4j/impl/main/slf4j-jboss-logmanager-1.0.3.GA.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/ejb-client/main/jboss-ejb-client-2.1.4.Final.jar
  [WILDFLY10_DIR]/modules/system/layers/base/io/netty/main/netty-all-4.0.32.Final.jar
```

You can add something like this if you have problems with logging:

```
  InternalLoggerFactory.setDefaultFactory(new Log4JLoggerFactory());
  PropertyConfigurator.configure("conf/log4j.properties");
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that Answer given by Rudik is not yet accepted , hence posting my take on this problem.

**Test case**

```
 @Test
    public void sendMessagesToWildfly10() throws IOException, NamingException {
        String Message = "Hello, World!";
        String connectionFactoryJNDIName = "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";
        String queueName = "jms/queue/TestQueue";
        Context namingContext = null;
        JMSContext context = null;
        try {
            Properties env = new Properties();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8470");
            // Below May Not be needed if you have turned off the security for Messaging
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "guest");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "guest");
            namingContext = new InitialContext(env);
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) namingContext.lookup(connectionFactoryJNDIName);
            Destination destination = (Destination) namingContext.lookup(queueName);
            context = connectionFactory.createContext("userName", "password");
            JMSProducer producer = context.createProducer();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                producer.send(destination, Message+" - "+i);
              }

            JMSConsumer consumer = context.createConsumer(destination);

           for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                String text = consumer.receiveBody(String.class, 5000);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (namingContext != null) {
                namingContext.close();
            }
            if (context != null) {
                context.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

You will require below mentioned Jars/dependencies added to your classpath. Most of them you can find in Wildfly/modules

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If a JMS client is running within a WildFly application then the `org.apache.activemq.artemis` module must be added as a dependency on your deployment to avoid the *java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory*,
 e.g. as [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417564/whats-the-best-way-to-use-the-jboss-client-jar-in-a-wildfly-10-application/50329636#50329636).

Otherwise ( standalone java application) - the jboss-client.jar needs to be included into class-path.
Note: take the jboss-client.jar based on your target WildFly version because it differs between WildFLy 8 and 10.